# Excel error 1004 error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

Tags: excel, vba, macros

soy nueva en esto de macros en excel
Deseo extraer datos de columnas pero me marca error de:
Error 1004 Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Esto creo que se debe por como defini las variables, ya que si las pongo String si funciona pero no me extrae el dato en el formato que deseo

Este es mi código

```
    Sub Asistencia()

Dim ss As Workbook
Dim archivo As Workbook
Dim nombreArchivo As Variant

Set ss = ActiveWorkbook
nombreArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

If nombreArchivo = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
End If

Set archivo = Workbooks.Open(nombreArchivo)

Dim BB As String
BB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim CC As String
CC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Dim DD As Date
DD = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim II As Double
II = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B10:B" & BB).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C10:C" & CC).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D11:D" & DD).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("I11:I" & II).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("E5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B1")
Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C1")
Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D1")
Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("I1")
archivo.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Deberías definir las variables BB,CC,DD y II como Long en todos los casos, ya que estás almacenando el número de fila. Mira bien [Resumen de tipo de datos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Comment: Lo intentaré, thanks :)

Comment: Concuerdo con @Esei, cambia el tipo de datos de las variables `BB, CC, DD e II` a `Long o Integer`, en lugar de `String o Date `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en que quieres de definir las variables `BB, CC, DD e II` como tipos de datos de cadena y fecha, cuando en realidad deben ser tipos de datos numéricos.

Para solucionar el problema, simplemente cambia el tipo de datos de las variables `BB, CC, DD e II` a `Long o Integer`, en lugar de `String o Date`. Debería funcionar correctamente:

```
Dim BB As Long
BB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim CC As Long
CC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Dim DD As Long
DD = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim II As Long
II = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Me ha servido, gracias :)